# Drawing to a DC of an external app in Delphi

Tags: delphi, canvas

Is there any way to draw to a DC of an external app? My app starts another process and I would like if that app could draw to the panel of the caller app. In the caller app, I created a TControlCanvas for the panel and passed its handle as a command param to the called exe. In the called exe I created a TCanvas, set its handle to the value passed as argument. But when I draw to this canvas, nothing happens in the caller app. Is there any tricky way to solve the problem?

Comment: This isn't how the system works. That other window is going to get `WM_PAINT` messages and overwrite what you painted. You might get somewhere with an overlay window, but you'd need to hook in to any move/resize messages of the other window. Almost certainly anything that you can get to work will not be robust, and I'd be looking for other solutions to your problem, whatever it actually is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I could send the new sizes to the "drawer app" because there is a working messaging between the apps. The "canvas app" does not draw to this panel. This surface would be reserved for the output pf the "drawer app".

Comment: Oh, you control both processes?

Comment: Both process is our. The original problem : i cant dock an external window in my app (a 3D preview window). idea : if the external app could draw to my panel, i could dock it. we can modify both app to solve the problem.

Comment: Why not use your message channel to ask the other process for a bitmap for the panel, and then have the host process draw it. Seems like a bad business to have found yourself in with one more process than ideal. Is it too late to do everything in the one process?

Comment: @SOLIDDevelopper "*The original problem..*" - so, this looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) to me. You want to dock an external window, but instead of figuring out how to make that work (which is very possible. Modern browsers do this, FYI), you chose to instead draw the external window across process boundaries (which is less possible). What's stopping you from making the docking work the way you want? Please show the code you are having trouble with. Why are you spawning the external window in a separate process to begin with?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The other proceess is an another app, the 3D modul of the system. How can I doc a window of another process in a panel in my app? not a control, but a whole app window. is it really possible?

Comment: @SOLIDDevelopper if you control the code for both processes, then yes, it is possible. It's when you *don't* control both codes that you can [run into trouble](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683). But, as long as the child program is coded properly so its window expects to be docked to a window in the parent process, then it can be made to work.